# Lower resource consumption to Microsoft python extension?

Tags: python, visual-studio-code

The [python extension](https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode-python) from Microsoft has many nice features, but all may not be necessary to be active at once. When I turn on the extension, the CPU and memory get consumed rapidly which really slows down the computer. Is there any way to lower the resource consumption in the python extension?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most resource usage is due to IntelliSense/auto-complete. You can try using Jedi for IntelliSense or the language server to see if either gives you better results by changing the value of the `"python.jediEnabled"` setting.

Comment: Thanks. I will try that out. Is there an option to turn off only the IntelliSense part of the extension?

Comment: No, there isn't a way to completely shut off the system.

Comment: Enabling the Jedi engine as you mentioned and adjusting the `Jedi Memory Limit` seems to have solved the problem. Appreciate your help!